# SwiftUI mutiple bindings

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am having a MasterView Controller which contains a List and my Detail View Controller. The Detail View Controller will edit information about the dataset selected in MasterView.

As far as I understand, I will have to create a Binding in my Detail, so when I edit details, the details should change in my MasterView list aswell.

What is correct way of doing this? My detail view consist of multiple views aswell, where the edit is made. Do I have to push the information with a binding to all my lower views? Can I go from `@State -> @Binding -> @Binding` and still the first state will change?

I am using SwiftUI for MacOS.

That is how it looks (left the List View and right the Edit View)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for anything more complex as simple State / Binding to visually change some components of your UI, go ahead and use @ObservableObject / @ObservedObject or for really global sharing @EnviromentObject instead @State / @Binding. Put all the logic to your model, don't try to do it in your SwiftUI. It will save you a lot of trouble, bug finding etc.

UPDATE there is no better way than see the documentation

```
/// A linked View property that reads a `ObservableObject` supplied by an
/// ancestor view that will automatically invalidate its view when the object
/// changes.
///
/// - Precondition: A model must be provided on an ancestor view by calling
///     `environmentObject(_:)`.
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@propertyWrapper public struct EnvironmentObject<ObjectType> : DynamicProperty where ObjectType : ObservableObject {

    /// A wrapper of the underlying `ObservableObject` that can create
    /// `Binding`s to its properties using dynamic member lookup.
    @dynamicMemberLookup public struct Wrapper {

        /// Creates a `Binding` to a value semantic property of a
        /// reference type.
        ///
        /// If `Value` is not value semantic, the updating behavior for
        /// any views that make use of the resulting `Binding` is
        /// unspecified.
        public subscript<Subject>(dynamicMember keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<ObjectType, Subject>) -> Binding<Subject> { get }
    }

    /// The current model supplied by an ancestor view.
    @inlinable public var wrappedValue: ObjectType { get }

    public var projectedValue: EnvironmentObject<ObjectType>.Wrapper { get }

    public init()
}
```

Use it if all @Published properties, computed properties etc. are shared widely.

If the model is related only to subset of your Views, use Observable / Observed instead. There is a lot of tutorials and even some nice examples on stackoverflow how to use it.

```
/// A dynamic view property that subscribes to a `ObservableObject` automatically invalidating the view
/// when it changes.
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@propertyWrapper public struct ObservedObject<ObjectType> : DynamicProperty where ObjectType : ObservableObject {

    /// A wrapper of the underlying `ObservableObject` that can create
    /// `Binding`s to its properties using dynamic member lookup.
    @dynamicMemberLookup public struct Wrapper {

        /// Creates a `Binding` to a value semantic property of a
        /// reference type.
        ///
        /// If `Value` is not value semantic, the updating behavior for
        /// any views that make use of the resulting `Binding` is
        /// unspecified.
        public subscript<Subject>(dynamicMember keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<ObjectType, Subject>) -> Binding<Subject> { get }
    }

    public init(initialValue: ObjectType)

    public init(wrappedValue: ObjectType)

    public var wrappedValue: ObjectType

    public var projectedValue: ObservedObject<ObjectType>.Wrapper { get }
}
```

and finally you need some model, which has to conform to

```
/// A type of object with a publisher that emits before the object has changed.
///
/// By default an `ObservableObject` will synthesize an `objectWillChange`
/// publisher that emits before any of its `@Published` properties changes:
///
///     class Contact: ObservableObject {
///         @Published var name: String
///         @Published var age: Int
///
///         init(name: String, age: Int) {
///             self.name = name
///             self.age = age
///         }
///
///         func haveBirthday() -> Int {
///             age += 1
///             return age
///         }
///     }
///
///     let john = Contact(name: "John Appleseed", age: 24)
///     john.objectWillChange.sink { _ in print("\(john.age) will change") }
///     print(john.haveBirthday())
///     // Prints "24 will change"
///     // Prints "25"
///
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol ObservableObject : AnyObject {

    /// The type of publisher that emits before the object has changed.
    associatedtype ObjectWillChangePublisher : Publisher = ObservableObjectPublisher where Self.ObjectWillChangePublisher.Failure == Never

    /// A publisher that emits before the object has changed.
    var objectWillChange: Self.ObjectWillChangePublisher { get }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension ObservableObject where Self.ObjectWillChangePublisher == ObservableObjectPublisher {

    /// A publisher that emits before the object has changed.
    public var objectWillChange: ObservableObjectPublisher { get }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am now using EnviromentObject. However, how can I use it in a Navigation View. I have a selected Person, which I get via a State. But I want to send the Enviroment Person Object to it, not the selected one.

Comment: see the difference between ObservedObject and EnviromentalObject , I put the reference to doc in my answer.